# Firebase chat. How to disconnect from the server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase chat.

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                try {
                    if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        Message model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                        mMessageList.add(model);
                        getViewState().updateRecyclerView();

                        if(mCurrentPositionVisibleLost + 1 == mMessageList.size() - 1 || mCurrentPositionVisibleLost == 0){
                            getViewState().scrollToPositionBottom();
                        }
                    }
                }catch (Throwable throwable){
                    System.out.println("Error " + throwable.getMessage());
                }

            ......
```

How to disconnect from the server? And how do I upload only 10 messages when I log in?

Answer (score 0):

DatabaseReference.getDatabase().goOffline();